# Не работает Intellisense в Rider IDE в .cshtml файлах (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, rider

Решил попробовать райдер и столкнулся с тем что в проекте ASP.NET не работает Intellisense + не работает подсветка закомментированных блоков (скриншот прилагаю). При этом тот же проект в студии работает без нареканий и все там нормально подтягивает.
В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эээ, холиваров не надо :D
В каждом свои плюсы и минусы)

Comment: а у вас `Support for Razor` плагин включен? (т.к. Rider поддерживает cshtml)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten да, включен. Пробовал его уже и перезапускать, единственное чего пока не делал - не переустанавливал сам Rider...